# How do you compile a HLSL shader DX9 without preshaders?

Tags: hlsl, directx-9

I'm trying to compile a HLSL DX9 shader without preshaders, but the 9.29.952.3111 version of FXC displays invalid flags when using the /Op argument.
It's for a shader model 3 target.

Here's the command I used
fxc.exe /T ps_3_0 /nologo /E main /Od /Op /Fo"D:/shaders/pixel.hlsl" "nopreshader.fx"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: FYI - "9.29.952.3111" is ``D3DCompile_43.dll`` i.e. the DirectX SDK (June 2010). The exact command-line you pass to ``FXC`` is a good minimal repro.